# The Settings app crashes when trying to open it on the latest iOS 17 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, appium, simulator

After updating to iOS 17, the Settings app on the Simulator crashes for the iPhone 15 Pro. This happens on my Mac.

The use of the Settings for us was to add some certificates in order to use it to run some internal enterprise software. Pressing on the Settings flickers and then disappears. When my Mac try to reopen it I get the error message that this won't work with my version on Mac

I tried uninstalling and installing, restarting the simulator

Answer (score 2):

So the issue, which is very annoying, is due to how the simulators were coded with Xcode 15 for the iPhone 15 simulators.

You didn't mention it but I'm betting you're on Mac OS Ventura 13.6.

It seems the simulator is making an OS API call that is ONLY found in Mac OS Sonoma 14.

If you upgrade your Mac to 14.x Sonoma this issue will go away.

Your other option is to wait until they ship a new release of Xcode and 'hope'.  :-)

Best of luck!

Happy Coding.